# transaction fails when I call getRandomNumber() function from chainlink VRF v1

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, chainlink, ethers.js

I am using chainlink VRF v1 to get a random number. I am using ethers.js to call the getRandomNumber() function but it always fails with this message: `Error: transaction failed [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ]`

I have enought LINK in my contract so that is not the reason for this. Is there any other possible or anything wrong with my code?

my smart contract:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.12;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBase.sol";

contract VRFConsumer is VRFConsumerBase {
    bytes32 keyHash;
    uint256 requiredFee;
    uint256 public randomResult;

    constructor()
        VRFConsumerBase(
            0x844ECf0B33EB65e1EC34AEa0d082D39879169890,
            0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088
        )
    {
        keyHash = 0x6c3699283bda56ad74f6b855546325b68d482e983852a7a82979cc4807b641f4;
        requiredFee = 0.1 * 10**18;
    }

    function getRandomNumber() public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        require(
            LINK.balanceOf(address(this)) >= requiredFee,
            "Not enough LINK - fill contract with faucet"
        );
        return requestRandomness(keyHash, requiredFee);
    }

    function fulfillRandomness(
        bytes32, /*requestId*/
        uint256 randomness
    ) internal override {
        randomResult = randomness;
    }
}
```

my frontend code:

```js
const provider: ethers.providers.Web3Provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider((window as any).ethereum;
      );
const signer: ethers.providers.JsonRpcSigner = provider.getSigner();
    const vrfConsumer = new ethers.Contract(
      this.address,
      vrfConsumerABI,
      provider
    );
    console.log("Start");
    const vrfConsumerWithSigner = vrfConsumer.connect(signer);
    const tx = await vrfConsumerWithSigner.getRandomNumber({
      gasPrice: 3000000000,
      gasLimit: 2000000,
    });
    await tx.wait();
    const result: BigNumber = await vrfConsumer.randomResult();
    console.log(result.toNumber());
    console.log("done");
```

Comment: Where did you define the `address` and `vrfConsumerABI`?

Comment: this code is actually a snippet of a react component. I have imported the ABI from the artifacts folder and the address is defined above.

Comment: Are you sure that in that point ```this.address``` is returning the contract published?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check some functions in [Chainlink hardhat-starter-kit](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/hardhat-starter-kit)

- helper-functions.js
- tasks\random-number-consumer\request-random-number.js
- tasks\random-number-consumer\read-random-number.js